# Resume transfer of a single file by rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

In Ubuntu, I want to copy a big file from my hard drive to a removable drive by `rsync`. For some other reason, the operation cannot complete in a single run. So I am trying to figure out how to use `rsync` to resume copying the file from where it left off last time.

I have tried to use the option `--partial` or `--inplace`, but together with `--progress`, I found `rsync` with `--partial` or `--inplace` actually starts from the beginning instead of from what was left last time. Manually stopping `rsync` early and checking the size of the received file also confirmed what I found.

But with `--append`, rsync starts from what was left last time.

I am confused as I saw on the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/rsync.1.html) `--partial`, `--inplace`, and `--append` seem to relate to resuming copying from what was left last time. Is someone able to explain the difference? Why don't `--partial` or `--inplace` work for resuming copying? Is it true that for resuming copying, `rsync` has to work with the `--append` option?

Also, if a partial file was left by `mv` or `cp`, not by rsync, will `rsync --append` correctly resume copying the file?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To resume an interrupted copy, you should use `rsync --append`.  From the
man page's explanation of `--append`:

> This  causes  rsync to update a file by appending data onto the end of the file, which
>   *presumes that the data that already exists on the receiving side is identical with the
>   start of the file on the sending side.*  [...] Implies `--inplace`, [...]

Option `--inplace` makes `rsync` (over)write the destination file
contents directly; *without* `--inplace`, `rsync` would:

1. create a new file with a temporary name,
2. copy updated content into it,
3. swap it with the destination file, and finally
4. delete the old copy of the destination file.

The normal mode of operation mainly prevents conflicts with
applications that might have the destination file open, and a few
other mishaps which are duly listed in the `rsync` manpage.

Note that, if a copy/update operation fails in steps 1.-3. above,
`rsync` will delete the temporary destination file; the `--partial`
option disables this behavior and `rsync` will leave
partially-transferred temporary files on the destination filesystem.
Thus, resuming a single file copy operation will not gain much
unless you called the first `rsync` with `--partial` or
`--partial-dir` (same effect as `--partial`, in addition instructs `rsync`
to create all temporary files in a specific directory).

Comment: Thanks! If a partial file was left by mv or cp not by rsync, will rsync --append correctly resume the file copying?

Comment: @Tim In short, `--append` makes `rsync` believe that, if two corresponding files have different length, then the shorter one is identical to the initial part of the longer one.  So, yes, if you start copying a large file with `cp` and interrupt the copy process, then `rsync --append` will copy only the remaining part of the file.  (_Note:_ if `cp` is interrupted by a system crash, there is a small chance that the file contents and metadata are not in sync, i.e., the file is corrupted.  In this case, running `rsync` once more _without_ `--append` should fix the problem.)

Comment: So If I understand this correctly, there is no way to tell rsync to **verify a partial file and resume transfer to that partially transferred file**?

Comment: @Winny See TomG's answer below.

Comment: @Winny, very belatedly: for a local copy there is no sensible way to do this. For a network copy this is the default mode when you specify `--partial` without `--append`.

Comment: @Winny `--append` and `--append-verify` have a dangerous failure case: when the receiver's file is the same size or larger but has different data. I suggest a [solution based around `--no-whole-file`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545370/143394) instead.

Answer (score 30):

Be aware that `--append` implies `--inplace`, which itself implies `--partial`.

- By just using `--partial` you should cause `rsync` to leave partial
  transfers and resume them in subsequent attempts.
- By using `--append` you should cause `rsync` to both leave partial files and resume them next time. After transfer `rsync` should verify the checksum of transmitted data only.
- `--append-verify` includes the whole file in the checksum verification, including any portion transferred in a previous transfer.
- With either `--append` or `--append-verify` a failed checksum verification should cause the file to be re-transmitted completely (using `--inplace`)

You should be able to resume a `mv` or `cp` operation with `rsync` but you may want to use the `--append-verify` option for peace of mind.

Note that using `--append` causes `rsync` to copy *only* those files which have its size on the receiver shorter than the size on the sender (regardless of time stamps), or are absent on receiver. By documentation on this option:

> If a file needs to be transferred and its size on the receiver is the same or longer than the size on the sender, the file is skipped.

More info in the [man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)

Comment: `--append` and `--append-verify` have a dangerous failure case: when the receiver's file is the same size or larger but has different data. I suggest a [solution based around `--no-whole-file`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545370/143394) instead.

Comment: @TomHale the documentation suggests that in order for a file to be skipped it would need to have exactly the same size and modification time at both ends. If this is a plausible concern then `--checksum` should be used. I can't find it specified explicitly, but logically any of the resume-able options should imply `--no-whole-file` because `--whole-file` should be incompatible.

Comment: `--append-verify` will skip same or larger sized files *with different dates*, which may be "unexpected". There's no need to `--checksum` **all** files, as `rsync` will do a whole file checksum anyway, but only on what it transfers.

Comment: `--checksum` tells `rsync` to checksum the files *before* sending which ensures that all changed files are transferred, regardless of size/time. Have you got a source for the unexpected `--append-verify` behaviour as what you describe doesn't match with the documentation or my (limited) experience?

Comment: `--append-verify` refers to `--append` which says: `If a file needs to be transferred and its size on the receiver is the same or longer than the size on the sender, the file is skipped.` Even if a file needs to be transferred because of `--checksum`, it may still be skipped.

Answer (score 7):

David Schwartz is correct, `--partial` (or better, `-P`) does do what you want.  I verified this on a 37G file that was stopped ~8g into it, over a network.  rsync quickly scanned the first parts of the partial (showing progress as it was going thanks to `-P`), and then resumed the transfer to the end of the partial file.

Comment: A network copy is treated differently to a local copy, which is the issue here.

Comment: @roaima Do you have a source for that, or a document which explains in more detail what the differences are? I fail to find it in the (huge) manpage.

Comment: @JonasWielicki the man page alludes to it under the `--whole-file` option description.

Comment: @roaima Thank you very much! This also means that the proper workaround is ``--no-W`` (which actually works!)

Comment: @JonasWielicki it's exceedingly inefficient, which is why it's disabled by default. You really do not want to use `--no-W` unless you understand exactly what setting it means for local files. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181018/100397

Comment: @roaima Thanks. I think I am aware of the implications; if a destination is write-limited (and/or the partial destination file’s bytes are still in the cache), using ``--no-W`` makes sense, doesn’t it?

Comment: @JonasWielicki yes

Answer (score 6):

By default, `rsync` will enable `--whole-file` if transferring from local disk to local disk. This will restart an interrupted transfer from the beginning, rather than checking the parts that are already there.

To disable this, use:

```
--no-whole-file
```

Combining this with either `--inplace` or `--partial` will allow resuming the transfer later.

My alias for using `rsync` to copy is:

```
rscp='rsync -ax --inplace --sparse --no-whole-file --protect-args'
```

---

**Warning**: be careful of using `--append-verify` as it will **skip** any destination files which are the same size or larger.

Comment: For network transfers `rsync` compares source and corresponding destination files prior to transfer in order to send only those parts which have changed (delta-transfer). `--no-whole-file` tells `rsync` to do the same thing for local-to-local copying. The documentation doesn't suggest it would have any affect on resuming partial transfers of single files.

`rsync` will skip files with the exactly the same size and timestamps by design. Neither `--append-verify` nor `--no-whole-file` should change that behaviour but `--checksum` should work with either for peace of mind at the cost of disk IO

Comment: `--append-verify` will skip same or larger sized files *with different dates*, which may be "unexpected". There's no need to `--checksum` **all** files, as `rsync` will do a whole file checksum anyway, but only on what it transfers.

Answer (score 3):

You were doing it right `--partial` does what you want. It appears to be starting from the beginning because it always starts at the beginning of the list of file data chunks it needs to copy. The `--append` option is dangerous and will result in a corrupt file if the data does not match for some reason.

Comment: Local copies are not compared, they are simply overwritten (or with `--append` continued on from the byte offset).

Comment: To avoid data corruption, use `--append-verify` (implies `--append`)

Answer (score 0):

--partial leaves partial files when you interrupt rsync (otherwise it deleted the partial file.)

--inplace makes it update a file in place, instead of having a temporary file (like foo.xyz would have a file with a name like .foo.xyz.xxxxx, then rename it to foo.xyz when it's done transferring.)

--append just adds the "rest of" the file to the end of the existing one.

What's the difference between append and inplace?  inplace checks the existing portion of the file, and re-sends any parts of the existing file that have changed (and without --inplace, it checks the existing file, and copies the matching data into the temp file as it goes so it doesn't have to resend that data.)   --append would work fine in the case where you're interrupting and resuming transfer of some large file; but rsync cannot assume you're doing that so by default it checks the existing part of the file first.